# Deploy On save In Netbans 7.4

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, netbeans-7

I work with `Netbeans 7.4` and `JBoss 7`. I used `JSF` and `Primefaces` Framework.
When I make changes in code,  I run JBoss agan. It is very difficult.I have googled but result is empty. "Deploy on save " option not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is not working for you?Hot deploy can be used only to modify existing methods in you classes, you can't unfortunately add new methods or new classes, you will than need to perform a full deploy to your server. Also, in order to make that work, you need to check `Compile on save` option too.

In case need you need 'real' hot deployment (i.e. deploy also new class or methods), you can use [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/), it is not free but it is a huge time saver.